# Send file to api using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to send file to api using ajax , but form-data always null in both cases mentioned below

```
<form id="myformdoc">
    <input type="file" size="45" name="file" id="file">
</form>

           <script>
          $('#file').on("change", function () {
        
          // var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
          
          let myForm = document.getElementById('myformdoc');
          let formData = new FormData(myForm);

    
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formdata ,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (color) {
                ;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
    
});
</script>
```

Any idea why form-data always null ?

Comment: in form tag add   enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Ahmed Sunny , i tried but same problem , formdata always empty {}

Comment: you are trying to get a form by id  = myformdoc , but your form dont have that id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use
[formData append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to add files to your `formData` function.

Change your jQuery code to this below and it will work fine and you can get the files on your backend to save them.

If you have other inputs in your `form` you can `append` them as well if you like to.

```
formData.append('file', $(this)[0].files[0])
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('#file').on("change", function() {
  //Initialize formData
  let formData = new FormData();
  console.log($(this)[0].files)
  formData.append('file', $(this)[0].files[0]) //append files to file formData

  $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(color) {
      console.log(color);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Error occured');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" size="45" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that `new FormData('id_of_the_form')` will implicitly add all the form fields in the `<form id="id_of_the_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `multipart/form-data` in contentType parameter.